# Postgres fuzzy array intersection

Tags: postgresql, fuzzy-search

I'm using Postgresql 13 and my problem was easily solved with `@>` operator like this:

```
select id from documents where keywords @> '{"winter", "report", "2020"}';
```

meaning that `keywords` array should contain all these elements. Also I've created a GIN index on this column.

Is it possible to achieve similar behavior even if I provide my request like `'{"re", "202", "w"}'` ? I heard that ngrams have semantics like this, but "intersection" capabilities of arrays are crucial for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the matches are all prefixes.  Is that the general rule here?  If so, you would probably went to use the match feature of full text search, not trigrams.  It would require you reformat your data, or at least your query.

```
select * from  
   (values (to_tsvector('simple','winter report 2020'))) f(x) 
where x@@ 're:* & 202:* & w:*'::tsquery;
```

If the strings can contain punctuation which you want preserved, you would need to take pains to properly format them into a quoted tsvector yourself rather than just letting to_tsvector deal with it.  Using 'simple' config gets rid of the stemming and stop word removal features, which would interfere with what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it should do the trick, how an index for this column should be set up? It would be better to be able to match not only prefixes, but ok if other solutions are too complex for someone who don't know PSQL server programming stuff;

Comment: @fevgenym Can you redo the table to make "keywords" be a tsvector column, or does it have to stay a text[] column?